# Should a dryer drive motor spin if the thermal fuse is bypassed?

Tags: dryer

I have a Maytag Neptune Drying Center (MCE8000AYW) that will not spin the tumbler motor when the relay switch clicks.  The thermal fuse is bad and I ordered another one (replacement part as the OEM part is out of production); however, I am not convinced the new thermal fuse will fix the problem.

I can run 120 volts directly to the motor and it spins.  I can hear the relay switch click but the motor won't spin.  I temporarily clamps the two leads from the thermal fuse together and the motor will still not spin.

Is there additional logic from the thermal fuse that would prevent the relay from sending power to the motor?  I would think that my bypass test would have allowed me to confirm that replacing the thermal fuse is the solution.

Comment: Agree that, generically, a bypass of a *bad* thermal fuse should make things run (for *testing* only, please!) so that raises the question: How do you know thermal fuse is actually bad? I have had a thermal fuse go bad on a dryer (Kenmore) and replacing it solved my problem, but it is also possible that even if the thermal fuse *is* bad that there may other parts - e.g., thermostat - that died at the same time.

Comment: Did you check for voltage at the fuse and/or motor when the relay clicks?

Comment: Oh, I used an multimeter and the fuse is open.  The thermistor passed that test.

Comment: This place rocks.  After seeing 120 volts at the motor jumper, I just tried the bypass test again and it worked.  I think my first test of clamping the two leads together was not providing good contact.

Answer (score 1):

In this case: yes.  Bypassing the thermal fuse was a way to confirm that other parts were not the culprit of the drive motor not spinning.